# Scala compiler failed to infer type inside Spark lambda function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda, apache-spark-dataset

Suppose that I have this Spark code written in Scala 2.12

```
    val dataset = spark.emptyDataset[String]

    dataset.foreachPartition( partition => partition.foreach {
      entry: String => println(entry)
    })
```

When I run the code, the compiler gave this error

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to <path>/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] Code.scala:11:52: value foreach is not a member of Object
[error]     empty.foreachPartition( partition => partition.foreach{
[error]                                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 11, 2020 1:43:41 AM
```

Why did the compiler `partition` as an `Object` instead of `Iterator[String]`?

I have to manually add the `partition` type in order for the code to works.

```
    val dataset = spark.emptyDataset[String]

    dataset.foreachPartition( (partition:Iterator[String]) => partition.foreach {
      entry: String => println(entry)
    })
```

Comment: This is a problem caused because of the overload for java. You have to be explicit about the type, there is no workaround and I doubt **Spark** maintainers will do anything to improve the **Scala** API, they only care about the **Python** and the **Java** one.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that's strange considering that Scala is supposed to be the 1st class citizen of Spark.

Comment: That was true many years ago. And you can not blame them, is simple marketing the percentage of **Scala** users is a minority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of two overloaded versions of `foreachPartition` and Java-Scala interop.

If the code were only in Scala (this is minimal code and independent of Spark)

```
val dataset: Dataset[String] = ???

dataset.foreachPartition(partition => ???)

class Dataset[T] {
  def foreachPartition(f: Iterator[T] => Unit): Unit = ???
  def foreachPartition(func: ForeachPartitionFunction[T]): Unit = ???
}

trait ForeachPartitionFunction[T] extends Serializable {
  def call(t: Iterator[T]): Unit
}
```

then the type of `partition` would be inferred (as `scala.collection.Iterator[String]`).

But in actual Spark code `ForeachPartitionFunction` is Java interface whose method `call` accepts `java.util.Iterator[String]`.

So both options

```
dataset.foreachPartition((
  (partition: scala.collection.Iterator[String]) => ??? 
): Iterator[String] => Unit)

dataset.foreachPartition((
  (partition: java.util.Iterator[String]) => ??? 
): ForeachPartitionFunction[String])
```

are eligible and compiler can't infer the type of `partition`.

And inference in Scala is local so after compiler can see `partition => partition.foreach...` (and `java.util.Iterator[String]` doesn't have method `foreach`) it's too late to come back to typing `partition`.

Answer (score 1):

just like @Dmytro said, scala compiler can't infer which overload function it should apply. however there is a simple workaround you can use, by using this helper function:

```
  def helper[I](f: I => Unit): I => Unit = f
```

now all you need to do is:

```
dataset.foreachPartition( (partition:Iterator[String]) => partition.foreach {
      helper[String](entry => println(entry))
    })
```